# How to make axMozillaBrowser1 wait till it loads fully?

Tags: c#, .net, browser, mozilla

i am trying to reload a web page 3 times using "axMozillaBrowser1(Mozilla ActiveX Control)" but axMozillaBrowser1 control is not loading web page and it's waiting courser is blinking regularly but browser control is not loading web page.

How to make `axMozillaBrowser1` wait till it loads webpage .

this is my program code:

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
public Form1()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    progressBar1.Maximum = 3;
}

private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

}

private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    do
    {
        axMozillaBrowser1.Navigate(textBox1.Text);
        while(axMozillaBrowser1.ReadyState != MOZILLACONTROLLib.tagREADYSTATE.READYSTATE_COMPLETE)
        {
            Application.DoEvents();
            if (axMozillaBrowser1.ReadyState == MOZILLACONTROLLib.tagREADYSTATE.READYSTATE_COMPLETE)
            { 
                progressBar1.Value = progressBar1.Value + 1; 
            }
        }
    }while(progressBar1.Value != 3);
}
}
```

Comment: what you mean till load fully? your loop ( do-while ) don't lets it to load successfully. do you tested your last question ? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12098798/how-to-use-mozilla-activex-control-axmozillabrowser1-c-net

Comment: it's not working i had to click again & again to complete process.

this is the code i used from answer
[link]http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12098798/how-to-use-mozilla-activex-control-axmozillabrowser1-c-net[/link]
if i have to click again & again then what is the mean of loop.

the above code that i put in question is works for `webBrowser1` but this is not working for `axMozillaBrowser1` control it makes waiting courser blink but web-page is not loaded by `axMozillaBrowser1` control.

Comment: I don't understand why you want to load it 3 times ! in the last answer, in navigated event: the navigate function is called that when it done, navigated event-handler called. that is recessive and it makes it loop to 3 times

Comment: i want to navigate "3" times because i am using progresssBar with navigation. Once navigation completes progressBar.valur will increase "1" time and it will increse while (progressBar1.Value !=3) and webbrowser will navigate while (progressBar1.Value !=3)................ i am just using navigation to increase progressBar.Value

Comment: here is adding progressbar to webbrowser http://answers.yahoo.com/question/index?qid=20070916112017AApVMQ2

Comment: the above code that i used in my question is working well with `webBrowser control (instance of Internet Explorer)` but wen i use `axMozillaBrowser control (instance of Mozilla browse) is not working.` When i use axMozillaBrowser the waiting course is blinking but page is not loading. I am having problem in `while(axMozillaBrowser1.ReadyState != MOZILLACONTROLLib.tagREADYSTATE.READYSTATE_COMPLETE)` but when i use `while(webBrowser1.ReadyState != webBrowserRedyState.Complete)` then it works well so i think i am having problem with `axMozillaBrowser.RedyState` help me with this problem